# Converting WKNavigationResponse decisionHandler Objective-C to Xamarin C#

Tags: xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I need help in converting the following into C#. I have tried several ways but keep failing. I would like to use the following method to get the response cookies for authentication purposes.

```
(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler{
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)navigationResponse.response;
NSArray *cookies =[NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:response.URL];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
}

decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicyAllow);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, ended up just figuring it out myself, wasnt too bad.

```
[Foundation.Export("webView:decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:decisionHandler:")]
public virtual void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationResponse navigationResponse, Action<WKNavigationResponsePolicy> decisionHandler)
{
    NSHttpUrlResponse response;
    NSHttpCookie[] cookies_holder;

    response = (NSHttpUrlResponse)navigationResponse.Response;

    cookies_holder = NSHttpCookie.CookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(response.AllHeaderFields, response.Url);

    foreach (var cookie in cookies_holder)
    {
        NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.SetCookie(cookie);
    }

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicy.Allow);
}
```